# C#: SQLite is storing doubles as integers

Tags: c#, sqlite, types, int, double

When I try to insert DOUBLE values into my SQLite table, they somehow automaticly get converted into INT values, even when I define the attribute type to be DOUBLE or REAL. However, if I change the attribute type to for example VARCHAR it does correctly store the DOUBLE values I insert... The SQL statement for creating the table is of the form:

```
CREATE table (someAttribute DOUBLE)
```

and the INSERT query:

```
INSERT into table(someDoubleValue) // => e.g. 1.5932 gets stored as 1
```

If anyone knows why this is happening and how I can fix it (so that it actually stores the DOUBLE values as DOUBLE), it'd be much appreciated!

EDIT: The C# code would be like:

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE table1(someAttribute DOUBLE)", m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1('1.5932')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1";
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                Console.WriteLine("value: "+reader["someAttribute"]); //this will display an integer value instead of a double
```

Comment: Can you post some specific C# code showing the INSERT?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the c# related code. If it is not a c# project, please edit it to remove the c# tag ;-)

Comment: Where do you see them as integers? In the database table itself, or after you retrieve them?

Comment: @EdPlunkett After I retrieve them, but not if the attribute type is VARCHAR (then their correct DOUBLE values are displayed, as string though).

Comment: Just a tip, table is a keyword, either change the table name to another word or put between double quotes.

Comment: @user2999349 You're inserting a quoted string, not a `double`. The quotation marks mean it's a string. See Steve Danner's answer, just do what he says and you'll be fine.

Comment: Since the table has REAL affinity (which is what DOUBLE translates to), the string should automatically get converted to REAL as long as it looks like a REAL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a parameterized query.  I am guessing that the SQLite engine is converting your string to an INT and thus, losing your precision.

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE table(someAttribute DOUBLE)", m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table(@val)";
command.Parameters.Add("@val", 1.5932m);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This.  Also, drop the character `'` from around your value if you don't do it this way.  You're explicitly telling SQLite that it's inserting a string value into a double column, which is why SQLite is bothering with conversion in the first place.

Comment: While using a parameterized query and dropping the ' are both good advice, I will point out that the original should work.  Try entering:   "CREATE TABLE table1(someAttribute DOUBLE);
INSERT INTO table1 values('1.5932');
SELECT someAttribute, TYPEOF(someAttribute) from table1;" in the command line tool and see for yourself.  (Note, though, I have corrected "INSERT INTO table1('1.5932');" to the correct syntax "INSERT INTO table1 values('1.5932');".)